# Sql static port

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, azure

I am trying to use SQL Server over hybrid connection (Azure). The connection is working, based on `tcpping` from the Azure console. But I cannot connect to the SQL Server.

No logon attempts seen in Profiler. The SQL server is setup with tcp port and empty dynamic port. I followed the online doc for setup. But `sys.tcp_endpoints` gives me 0 in port and `is_dynamic_port` 1 for tcp default.

Why is my SQL Server instance still dynamic and static? I am guessing that this is my issue. I can connect via Management Studio to `server,1433` and I am on the correct instance. So it seems like the tcp port is working.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a VM? Did you install SQL Server from the marketplace? If so, which template did you choose? If not, have you setup the network security?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on this issue. Nice of you to try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have located my issue. The reason was that the hybrid connection doesn't support desktop windows versions. When installed on a server it worked like a charm.